How does this NPN transistor circuit work?

In this circuit, there are two 3 volt batteries and an NPN transistor.
When you blow into the microphone, the resistance switches from 1 k ohm to 10 k ohm, depending upon the loudness. The green LED would turn on whenever the switch is set to on.
However, when you blow into the mic, the light becomes brighter. Also, the resistor at the top left is 5 k ohm and the resistor to its right is 100 k ohm. How does this circuit work?

If those are the components, the circuit is not supposed to work and the LEDs should be damaged. There might be more to the circuit that it appears which may explain why the LEDs don't damage and the LEDs work.

Is there a Marshall amplifier hidden behind the multi-coloured plastic thing that you refer to as a circuit?

why did you use the dark background for the picture?

Just for those trying to understand the picture and question, that comes from a product series called "Snap Circuits". There's a similar circuit (without the microphone) being discussed at this EESE question/answer and the kits on Amazon can be found using, for example, B0000683A4 and B0764LMN97 as the page/product identifier.

ShadowK, The microphone is probably an elecret and the 5k resistor provides the needed operating voltage/current for it. The green LED bugs me. With the switch off, the red LED becomes reverse-biased (green LED cathode to red LED cathode and red LED anode to NPN base via 100k.) With the switch on the green LED is in parallel to the red LED. What page in the book does this come from, exactly? Can you photo that page and post it?

I can not read your schematic, but this is how a simple NPN works.
I used 15k for the input resistance and 10k/(10k+100k) * 6V to almost enable the NPN to "almost" switch on at 0.6V = 600 mV.
I say "almost", but it is logarithmic proportional control of collector current so at 540 mV on base-emitter (Vbe) the collector pulls down 115 uA and the Green LED is "OFF" (almost on). You can see that with the input switch open.  (see if you can click on it)
In the linked live "slow-mo" simulation there is a switch for the input and a slider to control the simulation speed.  Click the switch.

See if you can read the schematic or wave plots as the input goes high, the output is inverted going low pulling down the LED cathode (-) to emit light limited in current by the 1k series R.
I inserted several meters too.  You can stop/start , reset, and change speeds.
